# Android actionbar tabs and indicator width issue

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have an activity with action bar and action bar tabs. I am using appcompat for action bar. I have attached the screen shots. on emulator 4.4 and htc 4.1.1 tabs widths id correct but on nexus 4, 4.4 it adds some margin due to which it looks ugly.

**Edit**
how i am adding tabs.

```
 ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
  ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
  ab.setTitle("Purchase media");
  ab.setSubtitle("To share with members");
  ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Audios").setTabListener(this));
  ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Videos").setTabListener(this));
```

my style for tabs is as follow

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>
```

and tab indicator selector is as follow

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_example" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_example" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />
```

how it looks.
[image: wrong width of tabs and indicator]
how it should be
[image: correct width of tabs and indicator]

anybody have any idea about this behavior?

Comment: Are you using SlidingTabLayout?

Comment: nop. i am just adding tabs to action bar. i have updated the question

Comment: Are you using appcompat v21?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes i am useing appcompat v21